# Delete from a character to the left

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a column of numbers-hyphen-text (e.g.: `4122555 - Guy Hopkins Construction SIP Trunking`).

How can I get this down to just the seven digit account number?

Comment: What language are you using?  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on *get this down to just the 7 digit account number* you might not even need to SEARCH or FIND, just `=LEFT(A1,7)` would do (or replace `A1` with wherever your `4122555 - Guy Hopkins Construction SIP Trunking` is). But my +1 has gone to BryPie.

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution that probably gives OP what he wants. I spread my +1s around, one here and one for BryPie.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need code at all. Insert a column to the right of this column, go to the data tab, use text to columns delimited by "-". Then delete the unwanted column of text.

Answer (score 1):

use instr to find your hyphen then use the Left method to extract it

```
Dim myVal As String
myVal = "4122555 - Guy Hopkins Construction SIP Trunking"
Dim iPos As Integer

iPos = InStr(1, myVal, "-") - 1
    If iPos > 0 Then
        MsgBox Trim(Left(myVal, iPos))

    End If
```

Comment: How do I get this to work when all the cell values are different, except for the hyphen?

Comment: can you explain different better?  or show a couple more examples of the cell values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula

```
=LEFT(D3,FIND("-",D3)-2)
```

assuming the text is in cell D3

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("-",A1)-2)
```